# Rotating a point about the origin with a rotation vector

Tags: 3d, rotation, geometry, plane

Let's say I have two inputs, an arbitrary point `P(x,y,z)` and rotation vector `R = [rx, ry, rz]` where each component of the vector is a rotation along the x, y, and z axis respectively, in radians.

For an example input, let's say we have a point `P(0,0,1)` and a rotation `R` of `R = [0, pi, 0]`. Is there a simpler/faster way of getting the desired output of `P'(0,0,-1)` without using rotation matrices on each component?

Comment: For special cases like yours it may be possible to have a faster way. For generic cases, no.

Comment: You compute the product of the three rotation matrices once, and apply the combined matrix on all points.

Comment: Is this an XY problem? Why don't you want to use rotation matrices?

Comment: **rotation vector** is a bit misleading .... I would use **euler angles** term instead.